# How to store form data to a .docx file in mongodb using expressjs

Tags: mongodb, express

Hi am working on a content management where the user will fill the forms and later download this data in a word document. So far am able to save the form data to a database but i don't know how to achieve the later task can anyone guide me. Am using Mongodb and Express.js....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways of creating Word documents that follow a standard format is:

1. Create a sample document in Word, add some easily identifiable text where you want to insert your own data (such as "$headline", "$bodyofcopy" etc. or names of your specific form fields)
2. Save the document as "Word XML Document (.xml)" and add it to your express application.
3. When the user wants to export the form data, load the xml document and do a replace of each identifiable text with the values from the database.
4. Send the XML with replaced values, and the user's computer will identify it as a Word document (if Word is installed).

Comment: I Tried doing that but unable to parse the xml as it store tags in (<o:DocumentProperties>element_1<o:DocumentProperties>) these type of notations.  @ Anders Bornholm

Comment: I never parse the XML - I just treat it all of the XML as a string and replace my "variables" (such as $headline).